# MySQL - LEFT JOIN and NOT IN

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I try to avoid subqueries due to the fact they usually have much lower performance than a proper join.

This is my current NOT working query:

```
SELECT 
    a.`email_list_id`, a.`category_id`, a.`name`
FROM 
    `email_lists`AS a 
    LEFT JOIN `email_autoresponders` AS b 
        ON ( a.`website_id` = b.`website_id` ) 
WHERE 
    a.`website_id` = [...]
    AND a.`category_id` <> 0 
    AND a.`email_list_id` <> b.`email_list_id` 
GROUP BY 
    a.`email_list_id` 
ORDER BY a.`name`
```

This query works:

```
SELECT 
    `email_list_id`, `category_id`, `name` 
FROM 
    `email_lists` 
WHERE 
    `website_id` = [...] 
    AND `category_id` <> 0 
    AND `email_list_id` NOT IN ( 
        SELECT 
            `email_list_id` 
        FROM 
            `email_autoresponders` 
        WHERE `website_id` = [...] 
    ) 
GROUP BY 
    `email_list_id` 
ORDER BY 
    `name`
```

Is there any way to do this with a left join? I've tried a number of different options.

Comment: Never make an assumption about performance.   What is the timing for the working query?

Comment: .0014, but this is on a basic example, it is searching a total of 5 records. If it searches 5,000 records, I doubt it will perform the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After rethinking it a bit, this might work i believe:

```
SELECT 
    a.`email_list_id`, a.`category_id`, a.`name`
FROM 
    `email_lists`AS a 
    LEFT JOIN `email_autoresponders` AS b 
        ON ( a.`website_id` = b.`website_id` and a.`email_list_id` = b.`email_list_id` ) 
WHERE 
    a.`website_id` = [...]
    AND a.`category_id` <> 0 
    AND b.`email_list_id` is NULL
GROUP BY 
    a.`email_list_id` 
ORDER BY a.`name`
```

Comment: Not the same logic - `email_list_id` equality is not his join condition, so checking for NULLs there doesn't guarantee anything.

Comment: No records were returned -- I changed the join slightly and it did work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For starters, add the inequality check on `email_list_id` to the join criteria, instead of having it in your WHERE clause:

```
LEFT JOIN `email_autoresponders` AS b 
    ON ( a.`website_id` = b.`website_id` 
         AND a.`email_list_id` <> b.`email_list_id` )
```

Though I'm not sure the scenario you mention calls for vast optimizations, this is a way to use a join rather than a subquery...

Comment: @ djacobson -- I had tried that, it does not work by itself. For the optimization, I didn't ask this question to only answer this particular use, but I wanted to find the solution for similar problems, which is why I gave this question a generic title.